# Long start time of MC due to bash function

Tags: bash, terminal, mc

I have next `bash` function to ensure new-lines after commands:

```
user at terra in ~
$ echo "m"
m
user at terra in ~
$ echo -n "m"
m↵
```

And the function itself in a `.bashrc`:

```
function prompt_command {
    # get cursor position and add new line if we're not in first column
    echo -en "\033[6n" && read -sdR CURPOS
    [[ ${CURPOS##*;} -gt 1 ]] && echo "$(tput setab 1)↵$prompt_reset"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

When I have `PROMPT_COMMAND` set - the MC starts from 10 to 30 seconds, but when commented - almost instantly.

Why is the, and how can this be fixed without disabling this issue?

[`strace`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8485132/), better to look around `13:59:06`, there's a 9 seconds delay there... (normal [`strace`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8485133/) for compare)

Comment: Why not attach to `mc` with `gdb` or `strace`, check where it is waiting and add this info to your question?

Comment: @skwllsp Added, I think this would be enough.

Comment: `strace -c` is a wrong idea. What you need to do it to attach with strace in another session to your `MC` process when it suddenly freezes. something like `strace -t -f -p $(pidof mc)`. Or to do the same with `gdb`

Comment: It *starts* long. Between I press enter after `mc` and can actually see the mc.

Comment: If so you can instead of running `mc` run `strace -f -t -o calls.txt` mc` and look for long syscalls in calls.txt.

Comment: Ok, will try it later.

Comment: @skwllsp I added this.

Comment: It is waiting for input from stdin, as far as I understand. `3021  13:58:57 read(0,  <unfinished ...>
3019  13:59:06 <... select resumed> )   = 0 (Timeout)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MC runs bash in a terminal. It leaves `TERM` set to the same value as the terminal that MC is running in, but it appears that it buffers or filters some exchanges between the inferior shell and the terminal.

You may want to use different customizations when bash is running as a direct subprocess of MC. Since MC's inferior shell only shows the prompt line, there isn't much point in worrying about the cursor position: just systematically add a newline.

```
if [[ "$(ps -o comm= -p $PPID)" == "mc" ]]; then
  PS1=$'\n'$PS1
else
  function prompt_command {
    # get cursor position and add new line if we're not in first column
    echo -en "\033[6n" && read -sdR CURPOS
    [[ ${CURPOS##*;} -gt 1 ]] && echo "$(tput setab 1)↵$prompt_reset"
  }
  PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

It is waiting for input from stdin, as far as I understand.

```
`3021  13:58:57 read(0,  <unfinished ...>
3019  13:59:06 <... select resumed> )   = 0 (Timeout)`
```

You need to find what it is doing. However my guess:

```
read -sdR CURPOS
```

You can remove this `read` in order to try to fix the problem or change its timeout

Comment: Yes, this is `read`, thanks. Now I need to think how to improve this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20156527/1030110).